# How to resize DRBD disk on LVM?

Tags: lvm, drbd

this is my drbd config

```
resource mysql {

    protocol C;

    floating 10.100.101.1:7788 {
            device   /dev/drbd0;
            disk     /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol02;
            meta-disk       internal;
    }

    floating 10.100.101.2:7788 {
            device   /dev/drbd0;
    disk     /dev/VolGroup01/LogVol02;
    meta-disk   internal;
    }
}
```

disk on LVMs on both nodes was set to 50G, I increased it with LVM on both nodes +4G (54G total now)

but when I try to run

```
[root@db1 ~]# resize2fs /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol02
resize2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol02
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
[root@db1 ~]#
```

It says I can't. What should I do? Should I stop DRBD? And if so - should I do additional steps after resizing and starting up DRBD?

thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see the following documentation link

http://docs.linbit.com/docs/users-guide-8.4/#s-resizing

Comment: Just to prevent any linkrot causing issues in the future, the key points of that are, for online growth: 
`drbdadm resize <resource>`
or, if you know that the source is clean:
`drbdadm -- --assume-clean resize <resource>`